# How can I watch for deep (nested) changes in a vuex store?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

```
  created() {
    this.$store.watch(
      state => {
        return state.httpRequest;
      },
      (oldVal, newVal) => {
        console.log(oldVal, newVal);
      }
    );
  },
```

Doesn't trigger as `httpRequest` is an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `{ deep: true }` as the third parameter:

```
created() {
  this.$store.watch(
    state => {
      return state.httpRequest;
    },
    (oldVal, newVal) => {
      console.log(oldVal, newVal);
    },
    { deep: true }
  );
}
```

[Here's the documentation for the `watch` method.](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#watch)

Here's a simple example:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: { httpRequest: null },
  mutations: {
   changeRequest(state) {
     if (!state.httpRequest) {
        state.httpRequest = { foo: 1 };
      } else {
        state.httpRequest.foo++;
      }
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
 el: '#app',
  store,
  methods: {
    onClick() {
      this.$store.commit('changeRequest')
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.watch(
      state => {
        return state.httpRequest;
      },
      (oldVal, newVal) => {
        console.log(oldVal, newVal);
      },
      { deep: true }
    );
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.1.1/vuex.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="onClick">
    Click
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to map the state from your `vuex` in `computed` section via `mapState` to get the needed value

```
computed : {
   ...mapState('yourNameSpace', {
      httpRequest : state => state.httpRequest
   })
}
```